# Maven web project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2

I am using maven eclipse plugin, when inside eclipse i create a new project using maven web -app archetype, that project is not identified by server inside eclipse?

Please advice

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project the select Maven-> Update Configuration

Comment: I tend to use that option as the "make m2eclipse behave" button for whenever m2 starts being uncooperative. :)

Comment: Advice: *never* accept voodoo reasoning.  Either trust the tool or get one you trust.  m2eclipse::update-configuration should be used everytime you make changes to your project structure, including the pom.

Answer (score 0):

What i did actually was creating a dynamic web project through eclipse then convert it to maven project through M2E plugin, it worked for me this way